# how to change the size of a uiimageview appended to a empty array

Tags: arrays, swift, slider, append, cgrect

My swift code uses a button to place imageviews on a uiviewcontroller that parent from a empty array. The problem is I dont know how to effect the size of the invidicual imageview after it is placed on the uiview controller. When a imageview is click and then when the slider is moved the imageview should change size. However what is happening is the value when the slider is changed effects the next iamgeview that is placed on the uiviewcontroller. Pitcure below is included I circled what the slider should effect. This is a video of what I am trying to do https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ho6ID6XVEYw&feature=youtu.be.

```
import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController {

var sx = UISlider()
var count: Int = 0
var ht = -90
var ww = 80
var arrTextFields = [UIImageView]()
var b7 = UIButton()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    [b7,sx].forEach {
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview($0)
        $0.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
    }

    b7.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-115, y: view.center.y + 200, width: 70, height: 40)
    sx.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-115, y: view.center.y-200, width: 70, height: 40)
    b7.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addBOx), for: .touchUpInside)
}

//func that adds imageview.
@objc func addBOx() {


    let subview = UIImageView()


    subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    arrTextFields.append(subview)
    view.addSubview(subview)



    sx.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ji), for: .valueChanged)
    sx.minimumValue = 10
    sx.maximumValue = 150

    subview.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX - 0, y: view.bounds.midY + CGFloat(ht), width: CGFloat(ww), height: 35)
    subview.backgroundColor = .purple
    subview.tag = count
    let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGestured(_:)))


    subview.addGestureRecognizer(pan)



    count += 1
    ht += 50
    arrTextFields.append(subview)





}

@objc func handlePanGestured(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {


    let draggedView = gesture.view!
    view.bringSubviewToFront(draggedView)


    let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
    draggedView.center = CGPoint(x: draggedView.center.x + translation.x, y: draggedView.center.y + translation.y)
    gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
}

@objc func ji(sender : UISlider){
   ww = Int(sx.value)

}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea that needs to be implemented is to add the currentView variable to find out which view we want to change.

We also need to add some functionality to select the specific view that needs to be changed.

1) Add variable `currentView`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    var currentView: UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
```

2) Add [tapGestureRecognozer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer) to `func addBOx()`

```
@objc func addBOx() {

    ...

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGestured(_:)))
    subview.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

3) Add `handleTapGestured(_:)`

```
@objc func handleTapGestured(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    currentView = gesture.view
}
```

4) Update `func ji(sender: UISlider)`

```
@objc func ji(sender: UISlider) {

    ...

    currentView?.bounds.size.width = CGFloat(sx.value)
}
```

All code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var sx = UISlider()
    var count: Int = 0
    var ht = -90
    var ww = 80
    var arrTextFields = [UIImageView]()
    var b7 = UIButton()

    var currentView: UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        [b7,sx].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
        }

        b7.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-115, y: view.center.y + 200, width: 70, height: 40)
        sx.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-115, y: view.center.y-200, width: 70, height: 40)
        b7.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addBOx), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    //func that adds imageview.
    @objc func addBOx() {


        let subview = UIImageView()


        subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        arrTextFields.append(subview)
        view.addSubview(subview)



        sx.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ji), for: .valueChanged)
        sx.minimumValue = 10
        sx.maximumValue = 150

        subview.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX - 0, y: view.bounds.midY + CGFloat(ht), width: CGFloat(ww), height: 35)
        subview.backgroundColor = .purple
        subview.tag = count
        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGestured(_:)))


        subview.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

        count += 1
        ht += 50
        arrTextFields.append(subview)


        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGestured(_:)))
        subview.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    @objc func handleTapGestured(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        currentView = gesture.view
    }

    @objc func handlePanGestured(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {


        let draggedView = gesture.view!
        view.bringSubviewToFront(draggedView)


        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
        draggedView.center = CGPoint(x: draggedView.center.x + translation.x, y: draggedView.center.y + translation.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
    }

    @objc func ji(sender : UISlider){
        ww = Int(sx.value)

        currentView?.bounds.size.width = CGFloat(sx.value)
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you can add a textField and write the number that the element from your array needs to change.

And please, don't use variables like sx, ht, ww, b7 in your code.

You can read API Design Guidelines [here](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/)

[image]

Comment: This works however for me to get this to work I had to take away the ability to move the imageview around I had to delete func handlePanGestured. I need to be able to move the imageivew around as well as when tapped have the ability to change its width with the slider. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This works for both tapGesture and panGesture. Watch my updated video. What is your problem?

Comment: Your video is exactly what I am looking for can you just copy your whole code to your answer?

Comment: can you look at this other question I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59463648/use-tag-to-determine-the-task-a-slider-does-if-and-only-if-a-button-is-tapped. Thanks for your great work!